# Как отправить в wall.post большое сообщение? (VK Open API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api, веб-программирование

Столкнулся с проблемой, уже иссякли идеи. Суть вот в чем:
есть страница, на которой стоит WYSIWYG редактор, в котором пишутся новости. При отправке формы, данные пишутся в БД. Потребовалось добавить кросспостинг в группу ВКонтате. Т.к. без костылей на PHP этого реализовать не получится, то использую OpenApi и jQuery. Написал функцию:

```
function postVK(text, news_id, id_tape)
{
    //функция редиректа
    function redirectToMain()
    {
        if (action == 'subscribe'){
            location.href='subscribes.php';
        } else {
            location.href='index.php?id_tape='+id_tape;
        }
    }


    //преобразование мнемоники
    var HTML=function(){
        var x,mnem=
            {34:"quot",38:"amp",39:"apos",60:"lt",62:"gt",402:"fnof",
                338:"OElig",339:"oelig",352:"Scaron",353:"scaron",
                376:"Yuml",710:"circ",732:"tilde",8226:"bull",8230:"hellip",
                8242:"prime",8243:"Prime",8254:"oline",8260:"frasl",8472:"weierp",
                8465:"image",8476:"real",8482:"trade",8501:"alefsym",8592:"larr",
                8593:"uarr",8594:"rarr",8595:"darr",8596:"harr",8629:"crarr",
                8656:"lArr",8657:"uArr",8658:"rArr",8659:"dArr",8660:"hArr",
                8704:"forall",8706:"part",8707:"exist",8709:"empty",8711:"nabla",
                8712:"isin",8713:"notin",8715:"ni",8719:"prod",8721:"sum",
                8722:"minus",8727:"lowast",8730:"radic",8733:"prop",8734:"infin",
                8736:"ang",8743:"and",8744:"or",8745:"cap",8746:"cup",8747:"int",
                8756:"there4",8764:"sim",8773:"cong",8776:"asymp",8800:"ne",
                8801:"equiv",8804:"le",8805:"ge",8834:"sub",8835:"sup",8836:"nsub",
                8838:"sube",8839:"supe",8853:"oplus",8855:"otimes",8869:"perp",
                8901:"sdot",8968:"lceil",8969:"rceil",8970:"lfloor",8971:"rfloor",
                9001:"lang",9002:"rang",9674:"loz",9824:"spades",9827:"clubs",
                9829:"hearts",9830:"diams",8194:"ensp",8195:"emsp",8201:"thinsp",
                8204:"zwnj",8205:"zwj",8206:"lrm",8207:"rlm",8211:"ndash",
                8212:"mdash",8216:"lsquo",8217:"rsquo",8218:"sbquo",8220:"ldquo",
                8221:"rdquo",8222:"bdquo",8224:"dagger",8225:"Dagger",8240:"permil",
                8249:"lsaquo",8250:"rsaquo",8364:"euro",977:"thetasym",978:"upsih",982:"piv"},
            tab=("nbsp|iexcl|cent|pound|curren|yen|brvbar|sect|uml|"+
            "copy|ordf|laquo|not|shy|reg|macr|deg|plusmn|sup2|sup3|"+
            "acute|micro|para|middot|cedil|sup1|ordm|raquo|frac14|"+
            "frac12|frac34|iquest|Agrave|Aacute|Acirc|Atilde|Auml|"+
            "Aring|AElig|Ccedil|Egrave|Eacute|Ecirc|Euml|Igrave|"+
            "Iacute|Icirc|Iuml|ETH|Ntilde|Ograve|Oacute|Ocirc|Otilde|"+
            "Ouml|times|Oslash|Ugrave|Uacute|Ucirc|Uuml|Yacute|THORN|"+
            "szlig|agrave|aacute|acirc|atilde|auml|aring|aelig|ccedil|"+
            "egrave|eacute|ecirc|euml|igrave|iacute|icirc|iuml|eth|ntilde|"+
            "ograve|oacute|ocirc|otilde|ouml|divide|oslash|ugrave|uacute|"+
            "ucirc|uuml|yacute|thorn|yuml").split("|");
        for(x=0;x<96;x++)mnem[160+x]=tab[x];
        tab=("Alpha|Beta|Gamma|Delta|Epsilon|Zeta|Eta|Theta|Iota|Kappa|"+
        "Lambda|Mu|Nu|Xi|Omicron|Pi|Rho").split("|");
        for(x=0;x<17;x++)mnem[913+x]=tab[x];
        tab=("Sigma|Tau|Upsilon|Phi|Chi|Psi|Omega").split("|");
        for(x=0;x<7;x++)mnem[931+x]=tab[x];
        tab=("alpha|beta|gamma|delta|epsilon|zeta|eta|theta|iota|kappa|"+
        "lambda|mu|nu|xi|omicron|pi|rho|sigmaf|sigma|tau|upsilon|phi|chi|"+
        "psi|omega").split("|");
        for(x=0;x<25;x++)mnem[945+x]=tab[x];
        return {
            encode:function(text){
                return text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666<>\&]/g,function(a){
                    return "&"+(mnem[a=a.charCodeAt(0)]||"#"+a)+";"
                })
            },
            decode:function(text){
                return text.replace(/\&#?(\w+);/g,function(a,b){
                    if(Number(b))return String.fromCharCode(Number(b));
                    for(x in mnem){
                        if(mnem[x]===b)return String.fromCharCode(x);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }();

    //Спрашиваем, нужно ли добавлять запись в ВК
    if(confirm("Отправить запись в группу ВКонтакте?"))
    {
        //если да, то проверяем авторизацию, если нет, запрашиваем ее.
        VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);

        //основная часть функции.
        function authInfo(auth) {
            //если авторизация есть
            if (auth.session) {
                //удаляем все HTML-тэги из него
                var strippedText = HTML.decode(text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));
                //вызываем АПИ для добавления на стену
                VK.Api.call('wall.post', {owner_id: -123456789, from_group: 1, message: strippedText, attachments: 'http://www.site.ru/news/'+news_id}, function(r)
                {
                    //если пришел ответ - запись добавлена
                    if(r.response){
                        //сообщаем об успехе
                        alert("Запись успешно добавлена в группу ВКонтакте");
                        //и редиректим
                        redirectToMain();
                    }
                    //если ответ не пришел - репост отменен
                    else
                    {
                        //сообщаем об этом
                        alert("Запись в группу ВКонтакте отменена");
                        //редиректим
                        redirectToMain();
                    }
                });

                //если авторизации нет
            } else {
                //вызываем АПИ авторизации, и делаем рекурсию
                VK.Auth.login(authInfo);
            }
        }
        //ну а коль барин не желает репостить запись
    }else{
        //просто посылаем его редиректом
        redirectToMain();
    }
}
```

Она принимает текст поста при отправке из редактора, чистит от HTML-тегов и сущностей и отправляет запрос на апи wall.post. Функция отправки такая (не пинать, кто это делал - хз):

```
function save_message(){
    $("#bg_form_div").css('display','block');
    params = {
        id_tape:id_tape,
        action:action,
        id_message:id_message
    };
    var fields = $('#mess_form').serializeArray();
    for (i in fields ) {
        params[fields [i].name] = fields [i].value;
    }
    if ($('#t_content')[0]){
        var txt = CKEDITOR.instances.t_content;
        params['t_content']=txt.getData();
    }
    if ($('#foto')[0]) params['file']=$('#foto')[0];
    params['is_cats']=a_cats;
    var message='';
    JsHttpRequest.query('message.ajax.php', params,function(result, errors) {
        $("#bg_form_div").css('display','none');
        if (result&&!result.success){

            $.each( result.messages, function(i,n){
                message+=n+"\n";
            });
            alert(message);
        }
        if (result&&result.success){
            $.each(result.messages, function(i,n){
                message+=n+"\n";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                var news_id=message.substring(0,message.indexOf(':'));
                $.when(alert(message)).done(postVK($("#t_content").text(), news_id, id_tape));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            });
        }
    },true);

}
```

слешами указал место, в которое впихнул функцию отправки в ВК. По сути тут функция просто посылает данные аяксом на php файл, который грузит все в БД.

**Сама проблема:**

при отправке одного текста (например длинной в 2000 символов) - ВК его принимает без проблем, а при отправке другого (например 3000 символов, или 1500 символов) - ВК отвергает и разрывает соединение, но при этом принимает тот же текст после обрезки до, например, 500 символов. Есть подозрения, что это из-за ограничений метода GET (8192байт), но я не совсем уверен что 1к символов может столько занимать (кодировка файлов CP-1251)

Что это за тайная магия и каким заклинанием её избежать? Спасибо!

ЗЫ: jQuery версии 1.5 (выше никак)

UPD: права, которые запрашивает приложение, при scope=wall,groups,offline:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Open API и JavaScript SDK используют JSONP для обращения к методам API. JSONP, как известно, при каждом запросе создает элемент `<script>`, где к атрибуту `src` подставляет query-строку с переданными вами параметрами. Так вот у браузеров лимит на длину ссылки - [2000 символов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). Поскольку JSONP в силу своей реализации не поддерживает протокол POST, то на стороне клиента вы ничего не сможете сделать.

Если этот самый WYSIWYG-редактор является частью админки сайта (т.е. если новости могут писать только редакторы вашего сайта), то имеет смысл возложить кросс-постинг новостей на бэкэнд, в вашем случае - на PHP. Вам надо лишь создать приложение типа standalone (важно создать именно этот тип; другие приложения не могут использовать метод [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) со стороны сервера), получить безлимитный ключ с необходимыми правами, сохранить этот ключ где-нибудь в конфигах сайта и обращаться к методам API напрямую, используя cURL или любое другое решение для HTTP-запросов.

Comment: Приложение и есть standalone, но через PHP не получалось обращаться к wall.post - апи возвращает ошибку доступа. Но там я токен получал через код авторизации, видимо проблема в этом.

Comment: @Константин, получайте ключ доступа по схеме [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user).

Comment: Убил три часа сейчас на костыли для получения токена по это схеме. Получил, но при обращении в браузере https: / / api.vk.com/method/wall.post?access_token=1234567..... и т.д. получил знакомый ответ: {"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"}]}}

Comment: @Константин, достаточно просто открыть ссылку `https://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APPLICATION_ID&scope=SCOPE&response_type=token&v=5.60`, заменив `APPLICATION_ID` и `SCOPE` своими значениями. При указании прав доступа не забудьте добавить право `offline`.

Comment: Ну я так и делаю, но ответ все равно при обращении с полученным токеном такой, будто он получен через метод с кодом - права на доступ к стене игнорируются.

Comment: @Константин, вы точно в параметре `scope` указали право доступа `wall`?

Comment: да,  маска 8192+65536+524288=598016  стена, группы и оффлайн

Comment: @Константин, во-первых, `524288` - это `notifications`. Во-вторых, вы можете вместо битовой маски явно указывать права доступа вот так: `scope=wall,groups,offline`. При авторизации в приложении вам говорят, что вы разрешаете приложению доступ к стене?

Comment: С маской промахнулся, извиняюсь. Но сути не меняет, прав на стену нет, и приложение не просит. при scope=wall,groups,offline выводится окно, что приложу сейчас в вопрос сам.

Comment: @Константин, тогда я могу объяснить это лишь тем, что у вас все таки не тип standalone, т.к. приложения другого типа игнорируют право `wall` и делают вид, что вы его вовсе и не запрашиваете.

Comment: В том то и замес, что оно именно standalone - уже второе создал, для проверки - а ведет себя как веб-сайт...

Comment: Еще заметил странную особенность: если обращаться для авторизации по адресу: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=12345678 &‌​scope=wall,offline&response‌​_type=token&v=5.60- мне вместо токена выдается код, как при двухэтапной авторизации. Почему, если я явно указываю в запросе response_type=token? )

Comment: @Константин, ох, а вы правы. У меня тоже встречается такая проблема, но закономерность я понять не могу. Некоторые standalone-приложения отдают `code`, а другие - `access_token`. За два года ни разу с таким не сталкивался. Похоже, эта проблема достойна отдельного вопроса на Stack Overflow, а не обсуждения в комментариях.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49505/discussion-between-terron-and-).